# Can't read mp3 files Android using Java

Tags: java, android, xml, file, permissions

This is the MainActivity.java:

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        ArrayList<File> songs = fetchSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                        String[] items = new String [songs.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
                            items[i] = songs.get(i).getName().replace(".mp3", "");
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                })
                .check();
    }

    public ArrayList<File> fetchSongs (File file) {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        File [] songs = file.listFiles();

        if (songs != null) {
            for (File song : songs) {
                if (song.isDirectory() && !song.isHidden()) {
                    arrayList.addAll(fetchSongs(song));
                } else {
                    if (song.getName().endsWith(".mp3") && !song.getName().startsWith(".")) {
                        arrayList.add(song);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

FYI I am running this on a Physical Device which has Android 10.

The 'file' parameter in `public ArrayList<File> fetchSongs (File file)` function is not null and is a Directory but in the same Function if I run `file.listFiles()` that returns null.

I do have two mp3 files downloaded.

My AndroidManifest.xml File has declared the permission to Read External Storage:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

I don't know if this only works if you have if (if (songs != null)songs != null)an external SD card on your Device but I am running this on my Device's own Storage.

Edit: When I ran this on another Physical Device which had Android 9 It ran perfectly.

Any Help is much Appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: You do not have access to the root of external storage on Android 11+. Please use `MediaStore`.

Comment: which android version of your phone?

Comment: @Anna I am using Android 10

Comment: @CommonsWare I am running Android 10 on my physical device

Comment: It works perfectly if I run this on another Physical Device which has Android 9.

Comment: "I am running Android 10 on my physical device" -- however, other people will be running Android 11 or higher. If your app will only be used by you, and you will ensure that your app will only ever be used on Android 10 or older, use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as mentioned in the answer shown below. If your app will be distributed via the Play Store or similar channels, you need to take into account the "scoped storage" restrictions enforced on Android 1 and higher. Not only that, but querying the `MediaStore` will be orders of magnitude faster to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this inside the `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

In Android 10 and higher, they changed how external storage works (scoped storage), and this code snippet allows you to revert back to the legacy storage APIs in order to have full access to external storage

UPDATE: for Android 11 and later, either use the MediaStore API or use the `getExternalFilesDirs()` for your app-specific directory (please note that you will need to move songs from the external storage directory to the app-specific directory), the app specific directory is like below:

Android/data/com.companyname.appname

But for Android 10 (API level 29) compatibility, you could surround the file fetching code with an API level check, if the level is 30 and higher (Android 11 and higher) then use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, else use the legacy storage APIs

Comment: @CommonsWare I know, but this is a long term solution for Android 10 users

Comment: @OdedAhmed I updated the answer to include solutions for Android 11+